# Play 2.4 - How to inject akka actors using guice

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, guice

How to create an Actor in Play 2.4 so that it automatically injects the dependencies using Guice? I read a couple of posts where they have used GuiceApplicationBuilder and then create actors. I don't want to control how the play application in instantiated. Instead I just want to know how an actor instance can be created so that the dependencies are managed using Guice.

Create a RoundRobinRouter with 5 workers

```
class RouterActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val router = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(5) {
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
      context watch r
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    }
    Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }

  def receive = {
    case job: Job =>
    router.route(job, sender())
  }
}
```

Extend AkkaGuiceSupport and create a module where the RouterActor is bound

```
class RouterActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[RouterActor]("router-manager")
  }
}
```

Inject the RouterActor using guice DI based on the name of the actor in the RouterModule

```
class ScheduledReportGenerationService @Inject() (@Named("router-manager") serviceRouter: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case serviceInfo: ServiceContext => submitJobs(serviceInfo)
  }

  def submitJobs(serviceInfo: ServiceContext) = {
    serviceRouter ? serviceInfo
  }
}
```

How to initialize the ScheduledReportGenerationService actor so that Guice automatically injects the RouterActor? I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class vistoscheduler.ScheduledReportGenerationService for arguments []
```

I understand system.actorOf uses Akka to create the Actor and hence Guice cannot inject the dependency. The documentation is not so clear that I could not get this resolved.

```
class SchedulerBootStrap extends Actor {
  implicit val system = context.system
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.minute)

  def receive = {
    case "BOOTSTRAP_SCHEDULER" => bootStrapServices()
  }

  def bootStrapServices() = {
    lazy val scheduledReportGenerationService =    system.actorOf(Props[ScheduledReportGenerationService], "scheduled-reports-service-actor")
    scheduledReportGenerationService ? ServiceContext(1L)
  }
}
```

Comment: DId you enable your module in conf like `play.modules.enabled += "packagename.RouterActorModule"`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IndirectActorProducer`,

```
class GuiceActorProducer(val injector: play.inject.Injector, val cls: Class[_ <: Actor]) extends IndirectActorProducer {

  override def actorClass = classOf[Actor]

  override def produce() = {
    injector.instanceOf(cls)
  }

}
```

and create your service like,

```
val scheduledReportGenerationService = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[GuiceActorProducer], injector, classOf[ScheduledReportGenerationService]))
```

Just make sure you are using `play.inject.Injector`.

***Edit to add the working code*** with `com.google.inject.Injector`.

```
class Application @Inject() (injector: Injector, system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  def index = Action { request =>
    val scheduledReportGenerationService = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[GuiceActorProducer], injector, classOf[ScheduledReportGenerationService]))
    scheduledReportGenerationService ! "some"
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}

class RouterActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case x: String =>
      log.info(x)
  }
}

class ScheduledReportGenerationService @Inject() (@Named("router-manager") serviceRouter: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.minute)
  def receive = {
    case serviceInfo: String => submitJobs(serviceInfo)
  }

  def submitJobs(serviceInfo: String) = {
    log.info("service")
    serviceRouter ? serviceInfo
  }
}

class RouterActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[RouterActor]("router-manager")
  }
}



class GuiceActorProducer(val injector: Injector, val cls: Class[_ <: Actor]) extends IndirectActorProducer {

  override def actorClass = cls

  override def produce() = {
    injector.getInstance(cls)
  }
}
```

There is another way to do this using akka `Extension`. See [this project](https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice/blob/master/src/main/scala/sample/CountingActor.scala).

Comment: In the statement val scheduledReportGenerationService = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[GuiceActorProducer], injector, classOf[ScheduledReportGenerationService])), how do I get an instance of play.inject.Injector?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/api/java/play/inject/Injector.html says that we should use the play underlying dependency injection (Guice). Also, in any case, I couldn't inject the play.inject.Injector as well. Can you please help?

Comment: How can I provide Assisted parameter using this method? For example, if the ScheduledReportGenerationService have a factory with 3 injected parameters and 2 assisted parameters, how can I pass them to the Props function?